# Replicate a header on a webpage using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a website with 5 different pages but the header on each page needs to be the same. I need to use an external javascript file (.js) to do this. The header contains the website name (as an image) as well as a navigation bar.

I have no idea where to even start with this. I've tried to create a function and write the information to the document (using document.write) but this doesn't seem to work. Am I going about it the wrong way? How could I get it to work?

```
Html code that I need to be repeated:

<header>
        <img id = "name" src = "StelluxStay.png" alt = "StelluxStay" />

        <nav class = "horizontalNAV">
            <ul>
                <li id = "current"> <a href = "Home.html"> Home </a> </li>
                <li> <a href = "#"> Villas </a> </li>
                <li> <a href = "#"> Facilities </a> </li>
                <li> <a href = "#"> Kids </a> </li>
                <li> <a href = "#"> Contact Us </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <hr>    
</header>

The javascript function that I have tried to create in an external .js sheet:

function repHeader() {
document.write (
<header> +
    <img id = "name" src = "StelluxStay.png" alt = "StelluxStay" /> +

    <nav class = "horizontalNAV"> +
        <ul> +
            <li id = "current"> <a href = "Home.html"> Home </a> </li> +
            <li> <a href = "#"> Villas </a> </li> +
            <li> <a href = "#"> Facilities </a> </li> +
            <li> <a href = "#"> Kids </a> </li> +
            <li> <a href = "#"> Contact Us </a> </li> +
        </ul> +
    </nav> +

    <hr> +  
</header> ) ;
}


I then call the function in the Html page.
<script type = "text/javascript">
        repHeader() ; //call function
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need quotes

```
document.write("<header><img id = 'name' src = 'StelluxStay.png' alt = 'StelluxStay' /><nav class = 'horizontalNAV'><ul><li id = 'current'> <a href = 'Home.html'> Home </a> </li><li> <a href = '#'> Villas </a> </li><li> <a href = '#'> Facilities </a> </li><li> <a href = '#'> Kids </a> </li><li> <a href = '#'> Contact Us </a> </li> </ul> </nav><hr> </header>");
```

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the quotes but it still isn't working.